# Highcharts window while decreasing not working

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I have a problem with `highcharts window resize handler`. 
If I put `chart container` into html table chart resize handler don't work while decreasing window width,but while increasing it works fine.

```
<table style="width: 100%; display: block;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is sample: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W9WWr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="container" style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
            </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

this should work

Comment: This works, but in real project chart width absolute position overrides other page elements: http://jsfiddle.net/W9WWr/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this then:

replaced the container `position:absolute` with `position:static` and you can regulate the size from the other div.

http://jsfiddle.net/W9WWr/2/

Answer (score 0):

highcharts width can be handled with div width in % try this:

```
 <div id="container" style="width:90%; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

[Here is Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W9WWr/3/)

Answer (score 0):

This is already reported on Highcharts bug tracker, but it's not considered as a bug, take a look: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1157